# Pre-populate default image in ACF image field on new posts

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

```
add_action('acf/render_field_settings/type=image', 'add_defult_image_field');
function add_defult_image_field($field) {
    acf_render_field_setting( $field, array(
        'label'         => 'Defult Image',
        'instructions'      => 'Appears when creating a new post',
        'type'          => 'image',
        'name'          => 'defult_value',
    ));
}
```

Adding this code to functions.php works as described to add the option for a default image in the ACF field editing screen.

However, the default image is NOT shown pre-populated in the ACF image field on a new post using ACF Pro and Avada 7.0.

How can I pre-populate the ACF fields with the default image for new posts?

Comment: Where are you setting the value for the default image that you want pre-populated?

Comment: What did you use as `default_value` ? ACF image value is the image's ID (from wp_posts).

Comment: I am choosing a default image in the ACF field edit screen and I assumed that this default image would then show up prepopulated when I create a new post that uses this image field. The new post does show the ACF field but it is not prepopulated with the default image. Must I add additional code to call the default value in new posts? I assumed ACF would do that for me.